# What season is it?

Tags: code-golf, date

## Task

When running the program must show the season according to the host computer's current time.

## Rules

- The output must be either: Spring, Winter, Summer or Autumn.
- The capitalization does not matter.
- The output must not contain anything else the the season names stated above.
- A season is 3 months and january is in this case the start of spring. (Northern hemisphere)

## Testcase

(program ran in January)

Output:

```
Spring
```

(program ran in April)

Output:

```
Summer
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Can we return one of `0, 1, 2, 3` instead of `Spring, Winter, Summer, Autumn`?

Comment: What ranges of dates are in each season?

Comment: And in mine, spring starts from march

Comment: What if I live in the Southern Hemisphere?

Comment: @IanMiller do you have other seasons there? for this challenge you need to output the season as in january is the start of spring december is the end of winter etc

Comment: And can someone tell my what is unclear as i would like to clear up any confusing things. The current anwsers all followed the challenge

Comment: @Ayoungcoder can you provide specific date ranges for "3 months"? Should we just use the solstices/equinoxes? And january is definitely winter...

Comment: Of course the Southern Hemisphere has different seasons. For example January would be the middle of summer. I therefore thought that January would be the middle of winter in the Northern Hemisphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>25</s> 16 bytes

```
“Ž¹Ž€È±–„“#žf3÷è
```

Explanation:

```
“Ž¹Ž€È±–„“        Push the string 'spring summer autumn winter'
          #       Split on spaces
           žf     Push month
             3÷   Integer divided by 3
               è  Index
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/8wNWFiMWX//@KAnMW9wrnFveKCrMOIwrHigJPigJ7igJwjxb5mM8O3w6j//w)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 40 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“¡ɗNʂ:ḲO¶Z{ṅ{Ḳ®⁵⁹¢»ŒV’:3ị“ȷ14ċ⁵¶<b_þṭ»Ḳ¤
```

Jelly has **no native date functionality**, yet this program prints `Spring` in January, February and March; `Summer` in April, May and June; `Autumn` in July, August, and September; and `Winter` in October, November and December.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYc6hhSen@51qsnq4Y5P/oW1R1Q93tlYD2YfWPWrc@qhx56FFh3YfnRT2qGGmlfHD3d1ADSe2G5oc6QbKHtpmkxR/eN/DnWsP7QbpWPL//38uBQA)**

#### How?

```
“¡ɗNʂ:ḲO¶Z{ṅ{Ḳ®⁵⁹¢»ŒV’:3ị“ȷ14ċ⁵¶<b_þṭ»Ḳ¤ - Main link: no arguments
“¡ɗNʂ:ḲO¶Z{ṅ{Ḳ®⁵⁹¢»                      - compressed string: " time.gmtime().tm_mon"
                   ŒV                    - evaluate Python code - gets the month, January=1 ... December=12 (the time module has been imported in the interpreter for the time formatting atom ŒT)
                     ’                   - decrement
                     :3                  - integer divide by three
                                       ¤ - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
                         “ȷ14ċ⁵¶<b_þṭ»   - compressed string "Summer Autumn Winter Spring"
                                      Ḳ  - split on spaces
                        ị                - index into (1-based)
                                         - implicit print
```

Comment: That is stupidly clever. Take a +1.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>32</s> <s>30</s> 27 bytes

```
`spÎAdä>H©umØC`qd gKg z3
```

[Try it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=YHNwzkFk5D5IH6l1bZjYQ4BgcWQgZ0tnIHoz&input=)

---

### Explanation

A compressed string of lowercase, separated season names delimited with `d` is decompressed by enclosing it in backticks. `qd` splits the string into an array on `d`s. The `g` method gets the element at the index of the current month (`Kg`) floor divided by 3 (`z3`).